# Need a push framework for android

Tags: android, node.js, redis, push, pusher

We need to achieve a push functionality in our chat application chat for android. We do not want to pursue the method of polling a http-endpoint based on a DB because that would mean polling, and its seriously going to drain the battery too fast.

So, we are looking for a realtime Push framework or a PubSub mechanism with channel subscription (each user will be aunique channelname for his lifetime). We have gone through the following:

- [Faye.js](http://faye.jcoglan.com) (based on nodejs and redis, but doesnt have an android library for clients)
- [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (but this has a limit of "active connection". This will not let many users be online since each user login will create a connection to pusher.com which is billed)
- [PubNub](http://pubnub.com) (same problem as Pusher.com)

Any messaging framework with android client library would do in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).